# How to select first row of the first table in an html page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Suppose if I have multiple tables in my HTML page (without their 'id' attribute), so how can I select first row of the first table or any specific table using jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 34):

```
$("table:first > tr:first")
```

or

```
$("table:first").find("tr:first")
```

or

```
$("table:first").children("tr:first")
```

or

```
$("table").eq(0).children("tr").eq(0)
```

So if I understand the followup question...

```
$("table:eq(1) tr:has(table:eq(2))")
```

translates to: get any tr's in the 2nd table's if the tr has a 3rd table

or

```
$("table").eq(1).children("tr:has(table:eq(2))")
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, its working (only second option).

But the next question is if I want to select any row of the second table in my page if it contains 3 tables. The command which you suggested is successful only for the first or the last table; what about the intermediate tables.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery is really flexible and I would need to see your html structure to provide accurate examples. The first example in my code would not work if you had <tbody> <thead> tags in your table for example. Please post some sample HTML and I can whip up the selectors

Comment: I'd suggest swapping `.children("tr:first")` for `.find('> tbody > tr, > tr')` since [some browsers add `tbody` to all tables and some don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858267/how-to-find-tr-inside-table-with-depth-1)

Answer (score 5):

Something you can use to select the nth row in the nth table:

```
$("table:eq(n) tr:eq(n)")
```

with n being the zero based index of the table or tr.

Example:

```
$("table:eq(2) tr:eq(4)")
```

gets the 5th row of the 3rd table.

Answer (score 2):

@svinto's answer is definitely the shortest, quickest and easiest way to accomplish this. If you're *really* concerned with performance (e.g. selecting within an arbitrary complex *for* loop), this might most likely prove to be a tad faster:

```
$('tr').eq(0)
```

If you need not use *only* jQuery selectors and actually require the DOM `<TR>` element, you can use:

```
$('table')[0].rows[0]
```

Alternatively:

```
$('tr')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `eq()` method you can specify the index of the element you want to get.
This will select the first row of the second table found in the DOM

```
$('table:eq(1) tr:first')
```

Comment: actually that will select the first row in the 3rd table. eq() is zero based

Answer (score 0):

Although not jQuery specific, I was introduced to dom selectors at this [w3c selectors page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos). It's very detailed but full of intricate examples.

Comment: and what the latest jQuery supports through their selector engine, Sizzle : http://wiki.github.com/jeresig/sizzle

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr:first");
```