# jQuery Finding first Row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to find the first row of a table using jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select first row of the first table in an html page using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) with a [`tr` element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), for example:

```
$("table tr:first")
```

Or for a specific table:

```
$("#myTable tr:first")
```

Comment: assuming your table id is myTable

Comment: @Shyju - For the second version, yes, the question's a bit unclear.  You may also want for example `tbody > tr:first-child` to select them in multiple tables...there are lots of approaches here :)

Comment: i dont think ive ever come across a jQuery question and not seen an answer by Nick Craver =) "The fastest hands in the wild west." +1

Answer (score 2):

Try the code `$("table tr:first")`

Answer (score 0):

If you have `THEAD` tag in your table and want to get the first row of the `TBODY` you need to execute:

```
$ ("#myTable tbody tr:first")
```