# How to select first row of the first table in an html page and highlight it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html-table, highlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select first row of the first table in an html page using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery)

Suppose if I have multiple tables in my HTML page (without their 'id' attribute), so how can I select first row of the first table or any specific table using jQuery selectors? and after that i can highlight it using any color.Actually I want to do it by code behind. I had tried but my bad luck. My code is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this, 
    this.GetType(), 
    "alert", 
    "<script language='javascript'>alert('hi');
        $('table:tableOne').children('tr:first').css('background-color', '#ffdc87'); 
        alert('end');</script>", 
    false);
```

As it showing there is any syntax error.

Comment: its not duplicate its similar to that but i think my requirement is some more than that.

Comment: adding `.css()` is not really a challenge is it ?

Comment: not but in my case its not working.. so i am asking here otherwise, i wouldn't sir.

Comment: if there is a concrete example please provide it and point out whats not working in detail that will help in getting better answers. As you see both replies can also be found in the other posts in my duplicate reference.

Comment: yes sir .. i got what you want to say so i am going paste my code here .. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will define a class "highlight" that has background yellow then select the first table of the first row and give it a class "highlight".

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr.highlight td { background-color:#ff0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('table:eq(0) > tr:eq(0)').addClass('highlight');
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for separating CSS values from jQuery, using `.css()` is icky.

Comment: @Interrobang he seperated it because thats the only way to do it correctly

Comment: @fyr: I'm sure you've been here long enough to see the trainwreck answers that add CSS properties directly using Javascript :P

Answer (score 0):

for first table first row:

```
$('table:first').children('tr:first').css('background-color', '#ffdc87');
```

for any table first row:

```
$('table').each(function(){
$(this).children('tr:first').css('background-color', '#ffdc87');
});
```