# Get the id of the table row with a partcular class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the id of a table row with a known class name.I am getting the data using ajax

...

```
 $.get("getall.php", function(data){       
    {
     $('.tableholder').append(data);
     $('tr:first-child').addClass("current");
```

Then giving the first-child the class current and that works as expected.However this returns undefined

```
var idcell  = $('table').find('tr.current').attr('id');
     alert(idcell);
```

Why is it returning undefined?.

Comment: Are you sure that It has a ID? Have you checked using chrome tools?

Comment: I just checked,and its kinda strange.It works if i add the class like         $('tr:first-child').next().addClass("current"); but that adds class to the second row of the table.

Comment: Could you try like `$('.tableholder').append(data); 
     $('.tableholder tr:first-child').addClass("current");` and then `var idcell  = $('.tableholder tr.current').attr('id');
     alert(idcell);` once..

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem.Instead of doing

```
$('tr:first-child').addClass("current");
```

i did

```
$('tr:first-child').next().addClass("current");
```

and it now works but the current class is applied to the second row.

Edit

To add the class current to the very first row i used this

```
$('tr:eq(1)').addClass("current");
```

I found this useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/839212/1867062