# Select one checkbox row only in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to be able to select only 1 checkbox at a time in Datatables.

In the example below, multiple rows can be selected. How can I go about only allowing one row to be selected at a time?

http://datatables.net/examples/api/form.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery
You could use jQuery to achieve it.

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Answer (score 3):

You could use Radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Example:

```
<input type="radio" name="fieldName" value="check1" />
<input type="radio" name="fieldName" value="check2" />
<input type="radio" name="fieldName" value="check3" />
<input type="radio" name="fieldName" value="check4" />
```

The "name" attribute is what groups the radio buttons together, the "value" attribute is what will differentiate them.

Comment: could you please share an example?

Answer (score 1):

[How to select first row of the first table in an html page using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838880/how-to-select-first-row-of-the-first-table-in-an-html-page-using-jquery)
Selects one row in a given table.
You could use jQuery to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the radio button,

```
<form action="path/to/form_submit_script.php" method="get">
  <input type="radio" name="red" value="Red" /> Red<br />
  <input type="radio" name="blue" value="Blue" /> Blue<br />
  <input type="radio" name="green" value="Green" /> Green<br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the working example [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/6AWae/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var _MainDataTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable();
...
$("#dataTable").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    if (_MainDataTable.$(".selected").length > 1) {
        _MainDataTable.$(".selected").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
});
```